# Scrape images from wall photo album on facebook

Tags: facebook, scrape

Is it possible to scrape the pictures and titles of an album of a facebook group? Any ideas or  know a good tutorial to get going with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like this is possible using the API.

You should be able to make a call to `/GROUP_ID/albums` to get the album_id in the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) then make a call to `/ALBUM_ID` to get the photos.

Both of these calls to groups I admin result in OAuth Errors: "(#3) App must be on whitelist"

Whitelisting apps appears to only be possible by a Facebook employee.

You could try manually scraping the album URL as though you were a browser, but this is not supported and could get you and your group banned.